# I’ve been searching the internet for days and I can’t seem to find out what insect this is, can anyone help?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]I saw this tiny insect and I first thought it was an ant because of the body shape. However its legs were really really green, I’m adding photos but it’s hard to see how green they actually were. It also moved like a spider, and not like an ant which I thought was curious. For reference I live in Norway. Sorry about the grainy pics but it’s a screenshot from a film I took. Hope someone can tell me!

Comment: First, count the legs. Have you tried looking for spiders?

Comment: Certainly looks like a spider.  How big was it roughly and do you have any other photos from other angles?

Comment: It was a bit larger than your average ant, not the brown/reddish ones but the black ones. I thought it was an ant first because the body looked too long to be a spider but it moved like one. It definitely had 8 legs, a black body with a few white dots (?) and very green legs. I have a film of it so I can see if I can screenshot other angles but I’m not sure how to post them in comments.. I haven’t used this platform before. Thanks for the reply by the way!

Comment: *Myrmarachne formicaria* [does occur in Norway](https://fauna-eu.org/cdm_dataportal/taxon/d3922b68-e3af-4b66-9b5a-a7c822013345), but the body shape doesn't fit: *M. formicaria* is much more elongated and has longer legs. Also it is at least partially of brown color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counting the legs (4 on each side, so 8 in total), it must be a spider. According to the compact body shape and the relatively large "head" ([prosoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_anatomy#Cephalothorax)), I guess it must be a [jumping spider (Salticidae)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_spider) (at least in Europe). Several jumping spider species are [known to mimic ants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_mimicry#Spiders), what also fits the ant-like moving.

A quick web search brought me to the genus [*Heliophanus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliophanus) which resembles the specimen on your photo (black body, white spots on the [opisthosoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_anatomy#Abdomen) and bright legs), whereof four species occur in Norway according to [Fauna Europaea](https://fauna-eu.org/cdm_dataportal/search/results/taxon?ws=portal%2Ftaxon%2Ffind&query=heliophanus&form_build_id=form-EitHB3It0Wht5j8-r842Sn-xI8-3kdpJ8S-EHWD_Ogw&form_id=cdm_dataportal_search_taxon_form&search%5BdoTaxaByCommonNames%5D=&search%5BdoSynonyms%5D=&search%5BdoTaxa%5D=1&search%5BpageSize%5D=25&search%5BpageNumber%5D=0):

- [*H. cupreus*](https://wiki.arages.de/index.php?title=Heliophanus_cupreus)
- [*H. dampfi*](https://wiki.arages.de/index.php?title=Heliophanus_dampfi)
- [*H. dubius*](https://wiki.arages.de/index.php?title=Heliophanus_dubius)
- [*H. flavipes*](https://wiki.arages.de/index.php?title=Heliophanus_flavipes)

According to the description on the [Spinnenforum](https://wiki.arages.de/) (only in German), all four of them match the given characteristics. So, a determination on the species level would need a microscopical dissection.

Comment: H.cupreus matches perfectly with the spider I saw. I’m actually really impressed you found it, I googled in both English and Norwegian but I couldn’t find a site that gave me a full overview of all spiders. I  spent an hour or two trying to figure it out. Thank you, I know you said it was quick but I appreciate the effort regardless!

Comment: It was an educated web search -- I identify arthropods since years and so knew what and where to search. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I found [this ant mimicking spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myrmarachne_formicaria). Could it have been a female? The green legs don´t fit and the 4(?) white dots. I don´t have much experience with spiders, but that might just be variation of their phenotypes.

This genus of spiders lives mostly in the tropics, but a few species occur in temperate regions. I didn´t deep dive into that, but if it is not *M.formicaria* (De Greer, 1778) there might be another palearctic species that matches your find.

Comment: I honestly don’t know if I’m replying to my own question or yours right now so sorry or not sorry. I saw the ant your referred to and it doesn’t fit in color or body type to be honest. The body is slightly too long. The white dots fits but the body was black and it had green legs. It could be a variation I guess but looking up spiders in my country and also other countries has resulted in nothing. I’m actually really puzzled and have gone through what I could find on ants and spider with green legs and still nothing..